# Android Scrollview not catching longclick

Tags: android, onclick, scrollview, android-alertdialog, onlongclicklistener

As said in the title, I have a scrollview that should be listening for longclicks, but isn't catching any. Nothing happens when I hold the scrollview- no logs, no haptic feedback, & no dialog.

Thanks in advance!

JAVA:

```
...
ScrollView text_sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.text_sv);
    text_sv.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            MMMLogs.i("click", "long-click recognized");

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(_this);

            builder
            .setTitle(name)
            .setMessage(DHMenuStorage.notification)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

            return true;
        }

    });
...
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/text_sv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:longClickable="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/Gray"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="-- Dining Hall Name --"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="28dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/note"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/Gray"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="-- Special note here --"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: Is there any OnTouchListener or OnClickListener in your code? They may interrupt the process of OnLongClickListener. Be careful on return values of the methods.

Comment: Not unless the tabHost creates its own -- The only other listener in this class is my OnTabChangedListener().

Comment: After further fiddling, I've found that the same listener works fine for the textview enclosed in the scrollview.. I don't really want to make 2 separate listener though. Can anyone explain this??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well I never identified the exact source of my problem, but I suspect it is some sort of conflict with the listeners that the scrollview requires for its own scrolling.

I worked around this problem by setting the exact same listener on the linearlayout instead of the scrollview. Simple. Hope it helps!

Comment: Its very strange and I can not find out why OnLongClickListener would work perfectly fine with a LinearLayout but not with a ScrollView :\

Answer (score 0):

Check out ScrollView's [OnTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29). It specifically allows you to fire a performClick() command when the scrollView registers a motion event. It seems that a ScrollView will intercept all touch events, treat them as motion events, and will not let the events bubble up to any parents as a click.

Which makes sense. If I'm touching a scrollView, I may want it to be a click on something inside the scrollview, but I don't want it to trigger stuff that's related to the parent of the scrollView.